# file_get_contents cannot retrieve html from correct url

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the response json from this [api](https://int.soccerway.com/a/block_home_matches?block_id=block_home_matches_30&callback_params=%7B%22block_service_id%22:%22home_index_block_homematches%22,%22date%22:%222018-05-20%22,%22display%22:%22now_playing%22,%22timestamp%22:%222018-05-20%2013:05:36%22%7D&action=filterContent&params=%7B%22display%22:%22now_playing%22%7D) call. For doing this I build the url in the following way:

```
$currentDate = date("Y-m-d");
$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");

$url =  "https://int.soccerway.com/a/block_home_matches?block_id=block_home_matches_30&callback_params=";
$url .= "{\"block_service_id\":\"home_index_block_homematches\",\"date\":\"". $currentDate ."\",";
$url .= "\"display\":\"now_playing\",\"timestamp\":\"". $timestamp . "\"}";
$url .= "&action=filterContent&params=";
$url .= "{\"display\":\"now_playing\"}";
```

so I executed the request:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($html);
```

I get:

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found

but the link is correct, infact if you paste the [$url](https://int.soccerway.com/a/block_home_matches?block_id=block_home_matches_30&callback_params=%7B%22block_service_id%22:%22home_index_block_homematches%22,%22date%22:%222018-05-20%22,%22display%22:%22now_playing%22,%22timestamp%22:%222018-05-20%2013:05:59%22%7D&action=filterContent&params=%7B%22display%22:%22now_playing%22%7D) you can see the correct response.

What I did wrong?

Comment: @user3783243 I tried to use the function `urlencode($url);` but same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL encode just the values that aren't URL parameters. e.g.

```
$currentDate = date("Y-m-d");
$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");

$url =  'https://int.soccerway.com/a/block_home_matches?block_id=block_home_matches_30&callback_params=';
$url .= urlencode('{"block_service_id":"home_index_block_homematches","date":"'. $currentDate . '","display":"now_playing","timestamp":"' . $timestamp . '"}');
$url .= '&action=filterContent&params=';
$url .= urlencode('{"display":"now_playing"}');
```

It also is a bit easier to use single quotes for the encapsulation, and I would use `json_encode` to build JSON strings in the future.

A `json_encode` example would be:

```
$url =  'https://int.soccerway.com/a/block_home_matches?block_id=block_home_matches_30&callback_params=';
$json['block_service_id'] = 'home_index_block_homematches';
$json['date'] = date("Y-m-d");
$json['display'] = 'now_playing';
$json['timestamp'] = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");
$url .= urlencode(json_encode($json));
$url .= '&action=filterContent&params=';
$url .= urlencode(json_encode(array('display' => 'now_playing')));
```

Comment: This seems to working +1 (I don't have much rep), could you please show me how can I use json_encode as you suggest for build the url string? Thanks